# When I set the delegate of a UIWebView's built-in UIScrollView, I lose the ability to pinch to zoom, how can I get it back?

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, uiscrollview, zooming, uiscrollviewdelegate

I am using a UIWebView to show a PDF. I need to track some UIScrollView events, so I set the built-in UIScrollView like this:

```
for(UIScrollView *s in webView.subviews) {

    s.delegate = self;

}
```

But the problem is that when I do this, I lose the ability to pinch to zoom (like I could before because the UIWebView's Scale Pages to Fit property was set). How come this happens? What can I do to fix it? I went ahead and implemented the UIScrollView shouldZoom method, but when I pass back the scrollView as the view to zoom on, it zooms from the corner, not where my fingers are.

Does anybody know a solution to this problem? How can I have the UIScrollView delegate set, and still retain natural zooming ability?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either handle the following events in your delegate:

```
– viewForZoomingInScrollView:
– scrollViewWillBeginZooming:withView:
– scrollViewDidEndZooming:withView:atScale:
– scrollViewDidZoom:
```

or save the original delegate

```
origDelegate = s.delegate;
s.delegate = self;
```

and forward the calls, e.g:

```
- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    return [origDelegate viewForZoomingInScrollView:scrollView]; 
}
```

Comment: That worked for the most part, but now the UIWebView that is being zoomed won't readjust it's display when I zoom. The result is that the text I've zoomed in on is really really blurry, and can't be read. Any ideas? Add: It acts as though I've zoomed, but haven't lifted my fingers because the view doesn't refocus until after you let up normally. Now, it's just staying blurry...

Comment: Like @Barum Rho said, you're messing with the UIWebView internals.  No telling what relationships/dependencies are getting disturbed when you reassign the delegate.  My guess is that one of the other delegate methods that you are overriding has code critical to what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @Stephen J. did you fix the problem with blurry pages?

Answer (score 1):

You are messing with some `UIWebView` internals. This feels like a bad hack, but I think you could forward all the `UIScrollViewDelegate` methods back to UIWebView in addition to doing whatever you need to do.

Also, `UIWebView` has many subviews. You should check and override the delegate just for the `UIScrollView`.

```
for (UIView *subview in webViews.subviews) {
    if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]]) {
        subview.delegate = self;
    }
}
```